# Display sub category description on archive - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i use this code for display description on category:

```
  <?php 
 global $post;
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat');
$terms = get_the_terms($category->slug,'product_cat', $args);

    $count = count($terms); 
    if ($count > 0) {

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo '<div class="prod-descr" style="direction:ltl;">';
            echo $term->description;
            echo '</div>';

        }

    }

?>
```

It work but display parent category description on sub category. I need to hide parent category description on sub category, and display only sub category description.

Any help?

Thank for your help

Comment: where do you want to display that?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work.

I'm not sure what you do here:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($category->slug,'product_cat', $args);
```

Because I believe `get_the_terms` needs an `ID`.
So in my example it's an ID (change the `'1'` with `get_the_ID()` or try something else to get the ID.

But maybe your `$category->slug` works as well. Or `$category->term_id`. You need to try.

```
<?php
//Get all terms associated with post in taxonomy 'category'
$terms = get_the_terms('1','product_cat');

//Get an array of their IDs
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');

//Get array of parents - 0 is not a parent
$parents = array_filter(wp_list_pluck($terms,'parent'));

//Get array of IDs of terms which are not parents.
$term_ids_not_parents = array_diff($term_ids,  $parents);

//Get corresponding term objects
$terms_not_parents = array_intersect_key($terms,  $term_ids_not_parents);


global $post;
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat');

    $count = count($terms_not_parents);
    if ($count > 0) {

        foreach ($terms_not_parents as $term) {
            echo '<div class="prod-descr" style="direction:ltl;">';
            echo $term->description;
            echo '</div>';

        }

    }

?>
```

Based on this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55921/96806).